# React Native render HTML to string for alert function

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, render, jsx

As the title said, i don't want to render in component, just to strings.

i want to pass it on Alert function

I know there are a lot of library for rendering html, but all of them render to component.

Comment: just create a simple function instead of component

Comment: @Satif yes but the still strings include html tag...  i got the data strings with html tags --> '<p>ads</p>

Comment: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: @Satif so basically i couldn't right ? because i can't a way too, i didn't create the API tho, everything written with html tags